# How to send right in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to make something like this:

```
function ajaxGetId(val)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getID.php", // Your PHP script URL
      data: { html: val } // Data you want to pass to the PHP script
    }).done(function( response ) {
      alert( response ); // Do something with what the PHP output or die silently
    });
}
```

and the php file is something like this for example:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
return $parts;
```

the problem is that I get a huge alert with alot of HTML tags in it. can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: you need to process $_POST['html'] in place of $_POST['url'] on your php page.

Comment: First, you need to use `$_POST['html']` instead of `$_POST['url']`. Then you'll have to use `echo $parts;` instead of `return $parts;`

Comment: if someone could help you, you should better check that answer, so that people can help you next time also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it's doing:

```
return $parts;
```

When you make an AJAX call, you're not calling a function in PHP.  You're requesting a page.  That page is, essentially, no different than any other page you'd view in a browser.  The only difference is in what that page renders.

Generally for AJAX calls you usually want to render JSON data.  Though you might also want to render HTML if, for example, you're loading some dynamic content into a page via AJAX.

That being said, in order to render information to a page you don't use `return`.  You can, however, use something like `echo`:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo $parts;
```

This would result in the response being the plain text representation of the posted `url` value.  (Note, you're also not *actually* posting a value called "url".  I think you mean to use: `$_POST['html']` instead.)

You can add further structure to this by echoing the value as JSON data.  For example:

```
echo '{ "url" : "' . $parts . '" }';
```

Then in your JavaScript code you would be getting an actual JSON object instead of plain text, and you can access its properties directly:

```
alert(response.url);
```

As your data gets more structured, you can use [PHP's `json_encode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to easily transform it into JSON data to echo to the client.

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

`html` instead of `url` and `echo` instead of `return`:

```
$url = $_POST['html'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo $parts;
```

in your ajax `data: { html: val }` this `html` the variable which you put to request.

Answer (score 0):

try using $url = $_POST['html']; instead of $url = $_POST['url'];

it will work fine